# Is it possible for the sequence $\{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\}$ to be unbounded but have $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$, $x_n \ne 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, examples-counterexamples

> Given:
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x \\
> x_n \ne 0 \\
> n \in \mathbb N
> \end{cases}
> $$ 
>   Is it possible for $\{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\}$ to be and unbounded sequence?

This problem comes in the context of two others which are:

1. Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ exist?

Not necessarily if we for example consider:
$$
x_n = \frac{sin{\pi n \over \sqrt2}}{n}
$$

2. If the limit exists and is equal to $q$, prove $|q| \le 1$

This one is also easy to show using the definition of a monotone sequence.

The third part as of the question section asks whether $\{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\}$ may be unbounded, and the answer suggests that this is indeed possible, but I don't see how.

What would be such a sequence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take
$$
x_n = \begin{cases}
 \dfrac{1}{n}, & \text{$n$ odd} \\[6pt]
 \dfrac{1}{n^2}, & \text{$n$ even.}
\end{cases}
$$

(If we assume $x \neq 0$, there is no such example.)